# Redirect with optional query string (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have coded a small PHP-Script, with which I have something like a short url.

`short.url/string`

gets directed to

`short.url/redirect.php?id=string`

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./redirect.php?id=$1
```

Some of these short URLs have query strings; unfortunately, I have difficulty combining query strings with the code above

`short.url/string?query`

should get directed to

`short.url/redirect.php?id=string&q=query`

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use QSA (Query String Append) flag in your rule

QSA flag is used to combine both new and old query strings.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./redirect.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```